# Number of ways to arrange numbers in matrix in A.P.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Find the number of ways to arrange the numbers from $1,2,...,n^2$ in an $n×n$ matrix such that the numbers in each row and in each column are in A.P.

Comment: AP = Arithmetic Progression?

Comment: @ajotatxe yes I meant that in abbreviated form

Comment: Hint: So $1$ and $n^2$ have to be in corners. Where can you place $2$? Where can you place $n^2 - 1$?

Comment: @HwChu can you plz say some more?

Comment: If a number lies in the interior of the square it has to be greater (and smaller) than at least 2 numbers. So 2 can only lie on the edge. Moreover, it should be adjacent to 1. Similar for $n^2-1$. Actually this already enforced almost everything. You can try to play with the $4\times4$ case to see what happened.